# How to list all the files in a specific google drive directory Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

What is the best way to list all the files of a specific google drive directory by folder ID.  If I build a service like below, what is the next step?  COuldn't findanything that worked for me. Service_Account_File in thsi example is a json file with tokens.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = service_account_file 
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list under the specific folder using the service account with python.

In this case, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the method of "Files: list" in Drive API with googleapis for python is used. But in this case, the files in the subfolders in the specific folder are not retrieved.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = service_account_file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

topFolderId = '###' # Please set the folder of the top folder ID.

items = []
pageToken = ""
while pageToken is not None:
    response = service.files().list(q="'" + topFolderId + "' in parents", pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items.extend(response.get('files', []))
    pageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

print(items)
```

- `q="'" + topFolderId + "' in parents"` means that the file list is retrieved just under the folder of `topFolderId`.
- When `pageSize=1000` is used, the number of use of Drive API can be reduced.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, a library of [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy) is used. In this case, the files in the subfolders in the specific folder can be also retrieved. At first, please install the library as follows.

```
$ pip install getfilelistpy
```

The sample script is as follows.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = service_account_file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

topFolderId = '###' # Please set the folder of the top folder ID.
resource = {
    "service_account": credentials,
    "id": topFolderId,
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
print(dict(res))
```

- In this library, the subfolders in the specific folder can be searched using the method of "Files: list" in Drive API with googleapis for python.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)
- [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, what is pagetoken here?

Comment: @ben890 Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `what is pagetoken here?`, all data can be retrieved using `pageToken` when the number of retrieved data is over `pageSize`. For example, when there are 1,500 files are existing in the specific folder, when `service.files().list(q="'#topFolderId###' in parents", pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()` is run, only 1000 data is returned. In order to retrieve the data from 1000 to 1500, `pageToken` is used. If this explanation is not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for this solution....got idea from this

Answer (score 1):

The file.list method has a parameter called q. you can use the q to [search](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#python) for things like files with in a directory.

Assuming you know the file id of the folder you are looking it you would do "parents in folderid"

This will return all the files within that folder.

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="parents in 'YOURFOLDERIDHERE'",
                                          spaces='drive',
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

Comment: Where do I put the id of the folder I'm looking inside?