# Calculate the size of a Google Drive folder with Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I would like to calculate the size of a Google Drive folder but the result is always 0.

```py
def get_folder_size(drive_service, folder_id):
    total_size = 0

    try:
        # List all files and folders in the folder
        results = drive_service.files().list(q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        for item in items:
            if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                # If it's a subfolder, recursively calculate its size
                total_size += get_folder_size(drive_service, item['id'])
            elif 'size' in item:
                # If the 'size' key exists, add its size to the total
                total_size += int(item['size'])

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

    return total_size
```

What is the problem with this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when `get_folder_size` is run, `total_size` is declared as 0 with `total_size = 0`.
- I think that `drive_service.files().list(q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents").execute()` returns no property of `size`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
def get_folder_size(drive_service, folder_id, total_size=0):
    try:
        # List all files and folders in the folder
        results = drive_service.files().list(q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false and 'me' in owners", pageSize=1000, fields="files(id,mimeType,size)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        for item in items:
            if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                # If it's a subfolder, recursively calculate its size
                total_size = get_folder_size(drive_service, item['id'], total_size)
            elif 'size' in item:
                # If the 'size' key exists, add its size to the total
                total_size += int(item['size'])

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

    return total_size
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this did the trick. There is just one issue I noticed. I applying for a normal folder ID it looks like it is working. But when I use "root" as ID for the whole "My Drive" I get a number which is way too much. I need to see if I can pin it down what it is.

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `But when I use "root" as ID for the whole "My Drive" I get a number which is way too much. I need to see if I can pin it down what it is.`, in this case, I guessed that the shared files might be included. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying the search query from `q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"` to `q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false and 'me' in owners"`? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: It looks more like that the folder size is multiplied with the amount of folders. 
For example I have a test folder which is 22.47 MB big and consists out of 6 folders. The script shows me the folder has 122.82 MB. Which is an exact multiplication by 6.

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `It looks more like that the folder size is multiplied with the amount of folders.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, when you want to retrieve all files under the root folder, I think that when all files are retrieved by `pageToken`, the process cost might be lower than that of the recursive function of your current approach.

Comment: The goal is to have a script, where I can simple add any folder ID I have access and I get the folder size. Whether this is the whole root of My Drive, a folder under My Drive, a shared folder or even a Shared Drive. For me the problem looks like, that each folder the script is checking, it multiplies the total size with it.

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Now, I noticed the reason for your current issue. So, please confirm my updated script again. I modified `total_size += get_folder_size(drive_service, item['id'], total_size)` to `total_size = get_folder_size(drive_service, item['id'], total_size)`, and added ` and 'me' in owners` to the search query.

Comment: @x0100 If you are required to include the shared files, please remove `and 'me' in owners` from the search query.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks. I did not add the "me" in owners because for my use case I want to see the whole size of a folder structure even when the owner is someone else. Now i just need to check where the file size discrepancy is coming. Because my Apps Script is telling me 773489185 bytes and my this python script 751417488 bytes. I guess I will also include a file count function to see if both scripts catch the same amount of files.

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue of `Now i just need to check where the file size discrepancy is coming. Because my Apps Script is telling me 773489185 bytes and my this python script 751417488 bytes. I guess I will also include a file count function to see if both scripts catch the same amount of files.`, I would like to support you. So, I would like to propose posting it as a new question. Because your initial question is to modify your showing script. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @x0100 If you post it as a new question, please include the information (both your Google Apps Script and your Python script) for correctly replicating your new issue. By this, I think that it will help users including me think of a solution.

Comment: It looks like i needed to adjust the pageSize and nextPageToken as just the first 100 items haven been loaded before: `results = drive_service.files().list(pageSize = 1000, q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents", fields="nextPageToken, files(id,mimeType,size)").execute()` or is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: @x0100 In order to retrieve all files using `pageToken`, these answers might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013967 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65281991